# What am I? Every day for most of us

Tags: riddle

> They put pictures on me
>   then take pictures of me
>   to share with the world
>
> But the pictures disappear
>   as my end draws near
>   and anxious heartbeats stilled
>
> I am sought after very wide
>   especially after every night
>   when things are put in motion
>
> And after a little while
>   I will be able to defile
>   your ability to sleep with devotion

**What am I?**

---

This riddle has been validated through [Sandbox submission](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/5292/10327).

Comment: I am little afraid after reading last stanza.....I love my sleep, +1 nice riddle

Comment: Definitely +1, I like how that little poem doesn't feel too "forced" to fit in the hints but actually sounds very smooth

Comment: I dislike the “anxious heartbeats stilled” line. (1) It’s easily interpreted as morbid.  (2) I don’t see how it fits the accepted answer.  When (that answer) is finished, it’s more likely to cause heartbeats to be accelerated and amplified.

Comment: The explanation by the accepted answer is not what I had meant by that line, but was close enough that I accepted and did not say anything about it. What I meant by it was that many people drink coffee or cappuccino to relax (this is way before caffeine causes your heartbeat and energy to rise, but I am relating here to the recreational act of sipping a warm beverage after a hard day's work or on a rainy day). Hope this makes more sense

Comment: I realize that it can be easily interpreted as morbid, but the "stilled" here refers to "calm", not "stopped", as in "still" waters

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are

> A Cappuccino

They put pictures on me
then take pictures of me
to share with the world

> Baristas create quite fancy artwork on the milk foam on top of your cup.
>  Many people take pictures of that and post it on Instagram, Facebook etc.

But the pictures disappear
as my end draws near
and anxious heartbeats stilled

> When the cup is empty, the milk is gone. 
>  "Anxious hearbeats stilled" refers to the addiction some people have towards coffee.

I am sought after very wide
especially after every night
when things are put in motion

> Many people drink coffee, especially in the morning (in Italy, you drink Cappuccino only in the morning, in the afternoon you would go for an Espresso). Coffee puts you in motion.

And after a little while
I will be able to defile
your ability to sleep with devotion

> Well, coffee can keep you from sleeping, after all that's why most people need it in the morning.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Nice try for a first answer :)

Comment: Thanks, and also thanks for formatting the above a bit nicer ;)

Comment: Well done, you got the answer quicker than I hoped :) What gave it away?

Comment: The first three lines. Taking pictures of sth. and "sharing" them reminded me of countless "food photographers" I know ;) then the last three lines somehow made the connection with coffee. Really nice riddle though!

Comment: Yes I thought the sleep bit would be a dead give-away; caffeine is one of the first things people think of when trying to stay awake or not being able to sleep (generally)

Answer (score 5):

You are:

> A television

They put pictures on me
then take pictures of me
to share with the world

> You put "moving pictures" on a television. Some people might take a picture of their new TV to share online with their friends.

But the pictures disappear
as my end draws near
and anxious heartbeats stilled

> After a person finishes watching TV, they power it off, causing the pictures to disappear. "Anxious heartbeats" could refer to the thrill that comes from an episode of a show that ends on a cliffhanger -- as you turn off the TV and move on with your day, you think about the show less, thus "stilling" your heartbeats.

I am sought after very wide
especially after every night
when things are put in motion

> Modern TV's are built with a wide aspect ratio. A person who is *really* into a TV show will want to sit down and watch more every night as the plot of their show picks up.

And after a little while
I will be able to defile
your ability to sleep with devotion

> As a person gets really caught up in their show, they may become "glued to the TV", giving up sleep in exchange for more time binge-watching their programs.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Good answer, +1

Comment: Hmm, I'll say this answer fits, but only because you really stretched some of the parameters. The correct answer was given by Michael Preischl :)

Answer (score 1):

It's

> a mobile as people  put pictures on it and take pictures of it.

Comment: How does this fit the rest of the clues?

Comment: I'm so out of touch with fads and fashion.  Do people actually *take pictures **of*** these things?  Or are they just, inevitable but incidentally, *included* in photographs?

Comment: You know, strangely enough, it is VERY popular on photo-sharing sites such as Instagram, where the cappuccino is the focus of the photo, especially with nice patterns or creative pictures